# How to have an annotation that creates getters and setters but without a field?

Tags: java

The code goes like this:

```
@AllArgsConstructor // lombok
class Message1 {
    ByteBuffer byteBuffer;
    // Wrap a bytebuffer
    public static Message1 wrap(ByteBuffer b) { return new Message1(b); }

    public int getVal1() { return byteBuffer.getInt(0); }
    public void setVal1(int val1) { byteBuffer.put(0, val1); }

    public int getVal2() { return byteBuffer.getShort(6); }
    public void setVal1(short val2) { byteBuffer.put(6, val2); }

    ...
    // more get and set of primitive types.
}
```

Can I have an annotation where I can do something like:

```
@MsgField(name="Val1", type="int", index=0)
@MsgField(name="Val2", type="short", index=6)
class Message1 {
    ByteBuffer byteBuffer;
    // Wrap a bytebuffer
    public static Message1 wrap(ByteBuffer b) { return new Message1(b); }
}
```

I am trying to read messages from a network tcp socket and use the offsets to read specific messages and their fields.

Comment: One could write a similar Lombok-style plugin which generates whatever methods they can think of, including what you're suggesting. You'd also need an IDE plugin to get your IDE to "understand" what methods were being generated, to prevent it showing errors for the methods which are generated at compile-time. I suspect that if you have to ask "how" then it may be beyond your ability right now. Lombok relies on non-standard compiler trickery; this style of code generation is not something that Java really aims to facilitate.

Answer (score 0):

Lombok probably won't be able to help here, however consider the following solution:

1. Create a non-java file that will act as a kind of DSL with all the relevant definitions (basically the data that you have in the annotation). It can be properties file, json, xml or any other format that can be easily parsed
2. Create an annotation processor (pretty much like a lombok itself) that will read these DSL files, parse the information in these files, and based on this information, will generate proper Java Classes with all the relevant methods.
   All this will happen during the compile time
3. Compile the java classes together with the other sources.

To implement the 'step 2' consider using the third-party tools - you don't really have to do it "from scratch". Example of such a library that I used once [Java Poet](https://github.com/square/javapoet)

The main idea of this approach is generating the whole set of classes like `class Message1` in your example. Since the DSL files are not java files by themselves, you won't need to face all the complexity of different syntax in different java versions that Lombok has to deal with, so it will be way more simple that the Lombok implementation.

Comment: "*Create an annotation processor (pretty much like a lombok itself)*" Lombok isn't an annotation processor, or at least not a traditional one. Annotation processors can only generate other classes or source files, they can't modify the bytecode of the class containing the annotation. The only way to modify the bytecode of a class containing the annotation is with undocumented compiler hacks, which is what Lombok does.

Comment: Totally Agree - I've used a somewhat simplistic approach in the answer: a "hook" into the compilation process itself - something that happens during the compilation process and generates source code files. As an entry point as far as I remember lombok requires an annotation processing, however the internals of the lombok are beyond the scope of the question I assume...